# Python VISA serial polling function

Tags: python, serial-port, polling, visa, gpib

I have an issue with one of my **GPIB** instruments. It is quite an old one, and it is stated as IEEE-488-1978. I have been trying to get the reference manual for that version of IEEE-488, but it has not been successful.

The issue regards the fact that in order to read the Status Register of the instrument it requires a **Serial Polling Function** (as its reference manual says). I do not know how can I do so in Python using **PyVISA**.

For example, what I am using to read from the device is `_instrument.ask("RV")_`, where `_RV_` means `_Read Version_`. Also, for writing a parameter like temperature, I do `_instrument.write("ST20.00")_`, where `_ST20.00_` means `_Set Temperature to 20.00 Celcius_`.

I have been trying to find an ASCII command to send to the instrument with the `_ask_` Python/VISA command and get in return the `_Status Register Byte_`, but there seems to be nothing feasible.

If anybody has a suggestion, regarding how to pass a serial polling function with Python/VISA, that could solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1975 the IEEE created the IEEE-488-1975 standard, describing a digital communication bus, sometimes refered to as [GPIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-488). It was revised in 1978. It described the hardware interface, but not the format of the commands and the data. In 1987 they introduced the IEEE-488.2-1987 standard describing Standard Codes, Formats, Protocols, and Common Commands.

Now back to your problem.

pyvisas `visa.GpibInstrument` class has a property called `stb` which you can use to access the status byte.
From the source:

```
@property
def stb(self):
    """Service request status register."""

    return vpp43.read_stb(self.vi)
```

So you can simply do

```
instrument = visa.instrument('GPIB::01')  # Assuming a GPIB device on channel 1
print instrument.stb  # Print status register
```

If your device conforms to IEEE-488.2, you have one more option. You can send the common command `*STB?`

```
instrument = visa.instrument('GPIB::01')  # Assuming a GPIB device on channel 1
print instrument.ask('*STB?')  # Print status register
```

Comment: Thanks P3trus, this has worked perfectly. I assume that the vpp43.read_stb is doing the serial polling I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Just the help I needed to start communicating with an HP 6034A that is too old to conform to 488.2 and way to old for VISA.